# JPA - Getting data from OneToMany relationship for a given condition

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm selecting a list of `objects` e from a `table`, and they have a `one to many` relations to objects in another table. I want to get all the objects but only get some of the other objects depending on a certain property. For example, a list of movies with each one having a series of actors associated with them, but I only want to get actors that have a salary assigned to them. The way it works right now it still returns all the movies with all the actors, with the only condition that at least one of the actors has a salary assigned to them:

```
SELECT m FROM movies LEFT JOIN m.actors a WHERE a.salary IS NOT NULL
```

I don't have experience with the way it works in JPA, not sure what would be the easiest solution for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, movies and actors have a many-to-many relationship - a movie can have many actors in it, and an actor would have acted in several movies.

However, assuming that the actor has acted in only one movie, and the actor entity has MOVIE_ID as the column for storing movie ID, using JPQL I would write my query as:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name FROM Movie m 
INNER JOIN Actor a ON a.movieId = m.id AND a.salary IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY m.id, m.name
```

To better help you, please add your Movie and Actor entity class.

Edit: Updated the JPQL query above to exclude movies where no actor is earning any salary.

Description: If you do LEFT join, you would get a list of all movies with or without your condition.

If you do inner join, you would get only those movies satisfying your condition of having at least one actor getting some salary.

However, with joins, you have will get multiple records for a single movie if there is more than one actor in a movie. To avoid that, use the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thank you. It was just a generic example, it was intended it to be one to many like in that assumption. However, this query seems to end up outputting the same result, the list of movies with all the actors in them regardless of whether that field is null or not.

Comment: Updated the query with description.